# Obscure 'StringIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This error is getting thrown on the substring method, and I've found many threads dealing with this issue but the problem I'm having seems to be different. I get that it will throw this error if your string is shorter than your substring(begin, end) size, but this error is thrown before anything is even passed into the method call.

I'm running a hibernate criteria:

```
    public static List<Object[]> baseQuery() throws HibernateException{
    Session session = getSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CsvDataEntity.class);
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("clearanceMainCat"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("clearanceDt"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("vertRadians"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("latitude"));
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);

    List<Object[]> list = criteria.list();
    return list;
    }
```

Then I'm using the query here:

```
    List<Object[]> fullList = baseQuery();
    String address = "400 Pine St, Seattle, WA 98101";
    String distance = "1";
    String years = "8";

    //create 'context' for GoogleMaps GeoCode API, geocode user-defined address
    GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext().setApiKey("Foobar");
    GeocodingResult[] result = geocode(context, address).await();
    Geometry coordinates = result[0].geometry;

    //store user request lat & lng from address supplied from form
    double longitude = coordinates.location.lng;
    double latitude = coordinates.location.lat;

    //user requested distance
    double requestedDistanceInMiles = Double.parseDouble(distance);

    //list to store all the crimes within the specified distance
    List<CrimeModel> crimeList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object[] record : fullList) {

        //verifying crime was commmitted within user-defined distance
        Boolean withinDistance = false;
        double rowLng = Double.parseDouble((String)record[2]);
        double rowLat = Double.parseDouble((String)record[3]);
        double milesBetween =     (haversineDistance(latitude,rowLat,longitude,rowLng,0,0)) / 1609.34;

        if (milesBetween <= requestedDistanceInMiles) {
            withinDistance = true;
        }

        //verifying crime was committed within user-defined time-range
        Boolean withinTimeRange =false;
        double requestedYears = Double.parseDouble(years);
        long requestedDays = Math.round(requestedYears * 365);
        String objectDate = (String) record[1];
        String recordDateAsString = objectDate.substring(0, 10);
```

The query works, and it returned a date + time string that is certainly more than ten characters. The weird thing is, I put a breakpoint at line 4, debugged, the query ran fine, but then it throws the error for way down at the bottom of the snippet I posted where substring() is called. In other words, my String should be of necessary length, but it's not even passed in before this error. Does anyone know why this would be thrown when it hasn't even been executed? I'm running this in Spring MVC, that's the only other thing I can think of that would cause some weird situation to occur. Thanks.

Comment: Please add your stacktrace. And besides your bug problem: read about the **single layer of abstraction** principle. Your code could benefit from that. Oh, very much it would.

Comment: Could you post the values of **fullList**?

Comment: Please, post the value of `objectDate`

Comment: objectDate would be "07/10/2015 12:24:32". And fullList ends up being 1.3 million object arrays, so I can't quite post the whole thing.

Comment: would be?  Or is?  Can you use your debugger to be sure?

Comment: Or, since you've got so many records, you could add this block before the `substring` call.  `if (objectDate.length() < 10) { System.out.println( "Short date: " + objectDate ); }` because there's probably just one record that's messing things up for you.

Comment: It is, I printed fullList(0)[1] to the console and that was the value. But what doesn't make sense is it never even reaches that point in the code, it just immediatly throws the exception after the query runs.

Comment: Well, as GhostCat said, please post your stack trace.  Also indicate which lines are mentioned in it.

Comment: @David Wallace you are probably right. But why would this error get thrown before that line of code gets run?

Comment: If you show your stack trace, someone will probably be able to tell you.  Without it, we'd just be guessing.

Comment: @David Wallace I had to ask this question before being away from my computer, so I will post it tomorrow. There are definitely some missing records in other columns, so it would not surprise me if this was the issue. Thanks for the suggestion, I'm fairly sure you are right. My guess is that because the list gets populated and stores in memory, and that I'm iterating the whole thing, it's already guaranteed that this error will be thrown, even though it hasn't gotten to that actual execution yet.

Comment: We are not saying the the stack trace will give us real help; we just can say: without more info, we definitely cant help.

Comment: @Ghostcat I looked at the stack trace carefully this morning and it was so short that there wasn't much to show. It just threw the error at this line:  `code` String recordDateAsString = objectDate.substring(0, 10); `code`. I was able to fix it by handling these, so I suppose I learned that if you populate a list, it's stored in memory and will throw the error even if you haven't iterated that specific list element. Also, I was reading about single layer of abstraction and that's something I've been working on improving, how would you change this (in general) to be more clear? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @David Wallace mentioned, because the database was so large, there were occasional missing records and after the List was populated from the query, the error was thrown. I did a simple handling of these to skip them (all four of the columns from the query needed to be handled due to missing records), and everything works fine.

```
            //skip null records in database
            if (objectDate.length() < 10) {
                continue;
            } else {
                recordDateAsString = objectDate.substring(0, 10);
            }
```